# "Features column 'Feature' not found" error using ML.net

Tags: c#, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, ml.net

I'm using ML.net to create a system that classifies emotions based on some training data, it was working until I implemented cross validation.

My pipeline code is (this also includes the cross validation code):

```
var featureVectorName = "Features";
var labelColumnName = "Label";

var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(inputColumnName: "label", outputColumnName: labelColumnName)
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate(featureVectorName, "leftEyebrow", "rightEyebrow", "leftLip", "rightLip", "lipHeight", "lipWidth"))
                .AppendCacheCheckpoint(mlContext)
                .Append(mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy(labelColumnName, featureVectorName))
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));

var model = pipeline.Fit(split.TrainSet);

#region CrossValidation
IDataView transformedData = model.Transform(split.TrainSet);
IEstimator<ITransformer> sdca = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.SdcaMaximumEntropy();

var cvResults = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.CrossValidate(transformedData, sdca, numberOfFolds: 5);

ITransformer[] models =
            cvResults
            .OrderByDescending(fold => fold.Metrics.MicroAccuracy)
            .Select(fold => fold.Model)
            .ToArray();

ITransformer topModel = models[0];
#endregion

using (var fileStream = new FileStream("model.zip", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write))
            { mlContext.Model.Save(topModel, split.TrainSet.Schema, fileStream); }
```

I then load up the model and create a predictor, which is where the error happens:

```
DataViewSchema predictionPipelineSchema;
ITransformer model = mlContext.Model.Load(@"model.zip", out predictionPipelineSchema);

//Create predictor using loaded model
var predictor = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<TrainingData, OutputData>(model);
```

A screenshot of the error:

[image]

The datatset being loaded is (just a small snapshot, the data set contains 15,000 feature vectors):

[image]

I can't figure out why it's having this error, since it worked perfectly before I implemented the cross validation code. I don't see why that would have an effect on the label of feature names in the model.

Comment: Please post your code as *text*; see why [an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: @desertnaut Fixed

Comment: Good, downvote retracted, but please do so for the exception as well - see why [an image of your exception isn't helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), too!

Comment: It may be because you saved the cross validation model instead of the fitted model.

Comment: @Jon Saving the fitted model does fix it, cheers. I'm new to ML so my understanding maybe isn't correct. But isn't cross validation meant to improve a model? So shouldn't it be the cross validated model that is saved for testing rather than the fitted one?

Comment: @BradyHarper Cross validation is a technique to see how well the model performs. If you do want something that runs to give you the best model then you can use AutoML :) Glad the issue was fixed!